# Creating a Kaplan Meier plot with Survival probabilities at time points

Tags: r, plot, statistics, survival-analysis

I'm trying to create a plot in R that would generate a table of the survival probabilities at specified points in time in a table.

Currently the plot looks like the following:

[image]

R code for the plot using the survminer package:

```
ggsurvplot(fit, 
           pval = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE,
           risk.table = TRUE, # Add risk table
           risk.table.col = "strata", # Change risk table color by groups
           linetype = "strata", # Change line type by groups
           ggtheme = theme_bw(), # Change ggplot2 theme
           palette = c("#E7B800", "#2E9FDF"))
```

Ideally I would like a table below the "Number at risk by time" to display the survival probabilities for each strata at times 250, 500, 750, and 1000.

I can retrieve the survival probabilities with the following code:

```
summary(fit, times=0:1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a function for that a wile back. It takes as an argument a survfit object and a time sequence and returns the survival probabilities.

```
ConstruirTabela = function(a, sequencia = seq(250,1000,by=250)){

quebra=NULL

for(i in 1:(length(a$time)-1)){
  if(a$time[i] > a$time[i+1]){
    quebra = c(quebra,i)
  }
}
quebra= c(quebra,length(a$time))

lsurv = list()
ltime = list()
previous = 0
for(i in 1:length(quebra)){
  periodo = c((previous+1):quebra[i])
  lsurv[[i]] = a$surv[periodo]
  ltime[[i]] = a$time[periodo]
  previous = quebra[i]
}

matriz=matrix(ncol=length(ltime),nrow=length(sequencia))
for(i in 1:length(sequencia)){
  for(j in 1:length(ltime)){
    indice = which.min(abs(ltime[[j]]-sequencia[i]))
    matriz[i,j] = lsurv[[j]][indice]
    }
}
retorno = as.data.frame(matriz)
f=strsplit(names(a$strata),"=")

names(retorno) = sapply(f, "[[", 2)
rownames(retorno) = as.character(sequencia)

return(retorno)}
```

It's probably not the best way to achieve this, but check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [ggpubr](http://www.sthda.com/english/rpkgs/ggpubr/index.html) library. Look at the very bottom of [this page](http://www.sthda.com/english/rpkgs/ggpubr/reference/ggtexttable.html). It shows a graph with a text table.

[image]

Comment: That does not appear related to survival analysis.

Comment: @42, you are right. but this is only to demonstrate how to put graph and table together easily.